# Convert string vector to *char

Tags: c++, vector

```
void getParameters(char *query) {


    vector<string> temp;
    vector<string> elements;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (query[i] == '\0') {

            temp.push_back('\0');

            // Here I want to convert temp values to string and append it to elements

            elements.push_back(temp);

            break;
        }

        if (query[i] == ' ')
        {
            temp.push_back('\0');
            elements.push_back(temp);

            temp.clear();

            continue;
        }

        temp.push_back(query[i]);

    }
}
```

I want to append as a string all values of **temp** vector to **elements** vector.

For example:

```
temp[0] = "t";
temp[1] = "e";
temp[2] = "s";
temp[3] = "t";
temp[4] = "\0";
```

Result:

```
elements[0] = "test";
```

I don't know the length of the **query** so this is why I'm using vector for **temp**.

The example of the **query**:

> select id from user

The final result should be:

```
elements[0] = "select";
elements[1] = "id";
elements[2] = "from";
elements[3] = "user";
```

Comment: You can use `strlen` to find the length of `query`. Or put it in a `std::string`. Or do your looping `for (int i = 0; query[i] != '\0'; i++)`.

Comment: You are confusing C-style strings with C++ strings. C++ strings shouldn't have `\0` manually added at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
std::vector<std::string> getParameters(const char *query) 
{

    std::vector<std::string> elements;
    std::stringstream ss(query);
    std::string q;
    while (ss >> q)
        elements.push_back(q);
return elements;
}
```

And then,

```
char *s="select id from user"; 
std::vector<std::string> elements= getParameters(s);
```

See [HERE](http://ideone.com/1OnfTw)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> getParameters(const char *query) {
    std::ostringstream split(query);
    std::vector<std::string> elements;
    std::string element;
    while (split >> element)
        elements.push_back(element);
    return elements;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one vector is enough. Of course, `stringstream` is much more simple.

```
void getParameters(char *query) {
    const int length = 10;
    char temp[length];
    vector<string> elements;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++, j++)
    {
        if (query[i] == '\0') {
            temp[j] = '\0';
            elements.push_back((string)temp);
            break;
        }
        if (query[i] == ' ')
        {
            temp[j] = '\0';
            elements.push_back((string)temp);
            j = -1;
            continue;
        }
        temp[j] = query[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str1 = "helo";
string str2 = "world";

string str = str1 + str2;
const char *cstr = str.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a short and neat way for solving the final step you are asking for. I.e. concatenate a vector of strings into one single string:

```
std::string concatenated = std::accumulate(temp.begin(),temp.end(),string());
```

Comment: Simpler is just to make `temp` a string to start with, then you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: I agree. I didn't mean to provide a better solution to his program, just an answer for the the concat-question he was asking.